# Find a Jordan canonical from $J$ of $T$ and a basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$ such that $J=[J]^{\beta}_{\beta}$

Tags: linear-algebra

For the operator $T:\mathbb{R}[x]_3\to \mathbb{R}[x]_3$ defined by $T(f(x))=f(x)+xf''(x)$.Find a Jordan canonical from $J$   of $T$ and a basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$ such that $J=[J]^{\beta}_{\beta}$

**Can any body tell me please is my solution right or wrong? Thank you **

Answer (score 0):

The basis for $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$

So..

$T(1)=1\\
T(x)=x+0=x\\
T(x^2)=x^2+2x=2x+x^2\\
T(x^3)=x^3+6x^2=6x^2+x^3$

so.. $A=[T]=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\0 
 &1  &2  &0 \\0 
 &0  &1  &6 \\0 
 &0  &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Hence the characteristic equation is $P_T(x)=(x-1)^4$

And $(A-I)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0 \\0 
 &0 &2  &0 \\0 
 &0  &0  &6 \\0 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

and $(A-I)^3=0$

Then $d_1=\dim N(A-I)=2\\
d_2=\dim N((A-I)^2)=3\\
d_3=\dim N((A-I)^3)=4$

We have $N(A-I)=\{(a,b,c,d)|c=d=0\}$ and $N(A-I)^2=\{(a,b,c,d)|d=0\}$

hence , We may choose $(0,0,0,1) $ to start our first chain , we get $(A-I)(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,6,0)$ and $(A-I)^2=(0,12,0,0)$ Now, in $N(A-I)$ We already have  $(0,0,12,0)$ . Hence to complete basis of $N(A-I)$ we take $(1,0,0,0)$ . Thus Jordan canonical basis is $\{((0,0,0,1),(0,0,6,0),(0,12,0,0,),(1,0,0,0)\}$ which is $\{x^3,6x^2,12x,1\}$

$f(x^3)=x^3+6x^2\\
f(6x^2)=6x^2+12x\
f(12x)=12x\\
f(1)=1$

Hence Jordan matrix  $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\1 
 &1 &0  &0 \\0 
 &1  &1  &0 \\0 
 &0  &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$